# USB Dongle causes static RF interference noise when listening to headphone

Tags: usb, audio, dell-inspiron

There is a strange issue on my Dell Inspiron laptop. When I access the internet through a connected USB dongle, I hear static noise in my headphones (RF kind of noise that usually comes when you bring your cellphone near a television). If I disconnect the dongle (even soft disconnect), the noise stops.

The weird thing is that the noise comes only when the dongle is connected in 2G mode, 3G mode works fine. Problem is that 3G isn't available across India yet, and many places I usually travel have only 2G connection.

The phenomena is constant, I've tried with all kinds of dongles - ZTE, Huawei, Micromax, etc. and with different headphones, it made no difference. I've researched a lot on the Internet, but couldn't find anything on this.

Comment: What type of connector do your headphones use?  What you describe is normal, electronics cause interference, and likely connected to a poor shielding your laptop has.  If you use a USB cable and increase the distance between your laptop and the modem does the interference still happen?

Comment: @Ramhound - The connector is a 3.5 mm jack which is the most common among laptops and headphones. Increasing the distance (between the headphone wire and dongle) reduces the noise a bit, but its still noticeable. The only thing I've observed is that decreasing the distance makes the noise almost unbearable.

Comment: I wanted you to use a USB extender port, if it's a shielding problem, doing so might solve the issue.  If a USB headset also catches the noise, not a great deal you can do about the noise, if it's a shielding problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hard-drive format and switching of distro (from Debian to Ubuntu) has solved this problem.